# Уникальный идентификатор компьютера

Tags: php, python, идентификация

есть приложение на `Python` и есть сервер, там уже всё на `php`.

Суть в том, что нужно как-то идентифицировать пользователя на сайте и в приложении, а потом всё это связать.

Человек скачивает на сайте, в бд заносится IP и дата

Пользователь устанавливает приложение и запускает его. При первом запуске отправляется запрос на сайт с IP адресом, полученным уже средствами `Python`, там идёт поиск по бд и если есть совпадение, то всё хорошо.

Но тут же есть и проблемы, человек может скачать приложение сегодня, а установить его через пару дней, что практически 100% означает то, что IP сменится.

Из чего сразу вытекает вопрос: **Как идентифицировать человека в двух разных языках?**

Была идея идентифицировать по материнской плате, но тут уже вопрос в том, а будет ли это идентификация? Как часто встречаются одинаковые платы?

В общем, идеи есть, но насколько они правильные - не знаю.

Comment: фигня затея. вдруг блогер милионник на твой сайт ссылку кинет или пранк какойнить будет ? милиона разных  материнских плат точно не существует. чем тебя не устраивает старая добрая регистрация через логин и пароль ?

Comment: @Интик к сожалению, регистрацию сделать нельзя, в этом и проблема, всё должно быть максимально просто

Comment: Здесь не будет просто. Проблемы с уникальностью пользователя на 100% не решаются.

Comment: @Apelsin2020 Нужно рыть в сторону fingerprint, чтоб хоть как то корректно идентифицировать пользователя.

Comment: в стиме можно глянуть самое популярное железо...очень у многих компы идентичные.железо это тупик в данном вопросе

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант №1**:

```
import subprocess
current_machine_id = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
print(current_machine_id)
```

Это просто, но только для OS Windows

**Вариант №2**:

Создайте уникальный идентификатор не по определенному оборудованию, а по определенному алгоритму из совокупности железа пользователя, например:

```
mainboard + GPU + SSD
```

В этом случае совпадения и ошибки идентификации будут минимальны. Пример по SSD:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193514/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-using-python

Comment: Да, идея хорошая, но это невозможно получить средствами php, если только подключить ко всему этому js, но вроде и на js это тоже нельзя сделать. P.s. Если ошибся - поправьте

Comment: Да, все верно -- на PHP надежно не сделаешь, можно только что-то вроде: $computerId = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'].$_SERVER['LOCAL_PORT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: @mr-js, у меня на сервере есть только  REMOTE_ADDR и HTTP_USER_AGENT, но потом с приложения можно узнать только REMOTE_ADDR , потому что HTTP_USER_AGENT это относится к браузеру

Comment: значит используйте только то, что Вам доступно в текущей ситуации... но опять же, на php это весьма ограниченно в целом, как я и говорил выше